# why no gaps between bars D3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am learning d3 js. I found a great book about the library. But I needed to translate the code examples from version 3 to 4. 
Here is my code on version 4

```
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var width = 800;
            var height = 500;            
            var dataset  = [];                    

            dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
                           11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];


            var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
                            .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                            .rangeRound([0, width], 0.5);

            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
                            .range([0, height]);

            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width",width)
                        .attr("height",height);            

            svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")               
                .attr("x", function(d, i){return xScale(i);})
                .attr("y", function(d){return height- yScale(d);})
                .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
                .attr("height", function(d){return yScale(d);})
                .attr("fill",  function(d){return "rgb(0,0,"+d*10+")";});

            svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("text")      
                .text(function(d){return d;})     
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")             
                .attr("x", function(d, i){return xScale(i) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;})
                .attr("y", function(d){return height - yScale(d) + 14;})                
                .attr("fill", "white");             

        </script>
    </body>
```

Here is the outcome [image]

As I understand, this

```
     .rangeRound([0, width], 0.5);
```

should bring some gaps between the bars. But, I don’t' know why - there are no gaps! 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the new pattern in d3 v4 would be -

```
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
      .rangeRound([0, width])
      .paddingInner(0.05);
```

Comment: what the difference between padding and paddingInner? Because with padding this also works well..

Comment: Have a look at this link - padding inner avoids adding padding at the first and last elements to keep it lined up nicely - https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-scale#band-scales - padding adds the spacing to both inner and outer.